# Onclick item on ListFragment open a new custom ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, android-listfragment

I have been working on a list fragment with certain items . on clicking on each item ,i need to open a new listfragment against that item in fragment. So im  posting my listfragment code ....

```
public class SellListFragment extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {

String[] menutitles;
TypedArray menuIcons;

SellCustomAdapter adapter;
private List<RowItem> rowItems;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, null, false);
}

@Deprecated
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    menuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < menutitles.length; i++) {
        RowItem items = new RowItem(menutitles[i], menuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1));
        rowItems.add(items);
    }

    adapter = new SellCustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
  //  ((CategorySelectedListener)getActivity()).categorySelected(position);
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), menutitles[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   ;
 }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Please tell me how to go to next listfragment

Comment: I didn't clearly understood what you want.

Comment: In  the above listfragment onclick on each item . ,i need a sub category list...my question is .. how to implement this scenario ..

Comment: Have tried creating a class extending `ListFragment` and then creating an instance of the class whenever `onItemClick()` is called?

Comment: do you want to replace the existing fragment with some other fragment?

Comment: my first fragment has a category list and onclick on each item  i need  a sub category in another fragment

Answer (score 1):

Create these arrayLists in you current `SellListFragment` at Class level.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> subCategoriesList=new ArrayList<>();     //Arraylist which will contain all the subCategories.
ArrayList<String> subCategoriesForCategory1=new ArrayList<>();        //ArrayList of sub categories for category 1.         
ArrayList<String> SubCategoriesForCategory2=new ArrayList<>();        //Repeat for as many categories you have.
```

In `onCreate()` fill your sub-category arrylists.

```
subCategoriesForCategory1.add("SubCat1");
subCategoriesForCategory1.add("SubCat2");     //Repeat as per your needs

subCategoriesForCategory2.add("SubCat1");
subCategoriesForCategory2.add("SubCat2");     //Repeat as per your needs

subCategoriesList.add(subCategoriesForCategory1);         //add to main arrayList
subCategoriesList.add(subCategoriesForCategory2);         //Repeat
```

Put this code inside `onItemClick()`

```
FragmentManager fm=getActvity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
FragmentToBeReplacedWith fragmentObj=new FragmentToBeReplacedWith();
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArrayList("subcategories",subCategoriesList.get(position));     //Repeat for as many values you want to pass. Explore for what suits your needs.
fragmentObj.setArguments(bundle);
ft.replace(R.id.id_of_fragment_container,fragmentObj);
ft.addToBackStack("setSomeUniqueName");  //Optional and nullable
ft.commit();
```

In `FragmentToBeReplacedWith` create a global arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> subCategories=new ArrayList<>();
```

In `onCreate()` of `FragmentToBeReplacedWith` do

```
Bundle bundle=getArguments();
subCategories=bundle.getStringArrayList("subcategories");
```

Now use the values in ArrayList `subCategories` where ever you need. 
Hope this helps.